# postgres select from json field as column for each key

Tags: json, postgresql

I have Items (id, data (json)) table. Data column structure is this:

```
   "somethingNotImportant":{
      "someName":"Its a name",
      "someProduct":"its a product"
   },
   "anotherNotImportant":{
      "installments":null,
      "baseRate":"30",
      "grossComm":"20",
      "totalMileage":null
   },
   "fleetdetails":{
      "4b4bd441-a8eb-4754-9384-6f97d1ee23e3":{
         "vehicleType":"43572386-5908-4e46-bf2b-3948df2e0e72",
         "usage":"Class 3",
         "carBand":"N\/A",
         "coverType":"Third-Party Only",
         "vehicleNumber":"1",
         "modelRate":"222",
         "technicalRate":"333",
         "annualMileage":"444",
         "adftExcess":"555",
         "wsExcess":"777",
         "annualBasePremium":null,
         "usageRate":null
      },
      "cc12cc77-9346-4cae-8c27-6afc8b457f9b":{
         "vehicleType":"fa999a90-b98f-499a-bef6-55b9a208c2fc",
         "usage":"Class 1",
         "carBand":"N\/A",
         "coverType":"Comprehensive",
         "vehicleNumber":"1",
         "modelRate":"2",
         "technicalRate":"3",
         "annualMileage":"4",
         "adftExcess":"5",
         "wsExcess":"6",
         "annualBasePremium":null,
         "usageRate":null
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to select and get fleetdetails results like this:

| item.id | vehicleType | usage | carBand |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43572386-... | Class 3 | N/A |  |
| 1 | fa999a90-... | Class 1 | N/A | and so on. |

How I can achieve this if I don't know fleetdetails json ids?

Comment: Please post the SQL query you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of `JSONB_EACH()` and `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` will do the things for you try below query:

```
select 
t1.id "id",
t2.value->>'vehicleType' "VEHICLETYPE",
t2.value->>'usage' "usage",
t2.value->>'carBand' "carBand",
t2.value->>'coverType' "coverType",
t2.value->>'vehicleNumber' "vehicleNumber",
t2.value->>'modelRate' "modelRate",
t2.value->>'technicalRate' "technicalRate",
t2.value->>'annualMileage' "annualMileage",
t2.value->>'adftExcess' "adftExcess",
t2.value->>'wsExcess' "wsExcess",
t2.value->>'annualBasePremium' "annualBasePremium",
t2.value->>'usageRate' "usageRate"
from items t1 cross join lateral jsonb_each(data->'fleetdetails') t2
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9d658ed5d05157b7d07f0f0e36b1e826)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jsonb_each()`:

```
select i.id, 
       d.detail ->> 'vehicleType' as vehicle_type,
       d.detail ->> 'usage' as usage, 
       d.detail ->> 'carBand' as car_band 
from item i
  cross join jsonb_each(i.data -> 'fleetdetails') as d(key, detail);
```

This assumes that the column `data` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's just a `json` column you have to use `json_each()` instead.